# SQL Server NULL check in SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that I need to UNION with another one and doing so I need to convert datetime value to true or false regarding on fact the value is or is not NULL.

Little example would be helpful:

```
ID | Value I have | Value I need |
---+--------------+--------------+
  1|    2018-05-02|          True|
  2|    2018-05-03|          True|
  3|          NULL|         False|
```

Please, is there any way to do it within `SELECT` clause? I tried `IIF` or `ISNULL` functions but they don't work the way I need.

Comment: `CASE WHEN YourColumn IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END`

Comment: IIF would do the trick. Show what you did and we can see where it went sideways on you.

Comment: or, using `IIF`: `IIF(YourColumn IS NULL, 'False','True')`

Comment: IIF is not working in the SELECT

Comment: If you provide the statement (and hopefully sample data) users can improve the code. Without the statement we're guessing and you are getting a slower, and possibly incorrect, response. If you have tried `IS NULL` and not getting the results you are expecting it could be a data problem.

Comment: @EzLo was right, Thank you, it is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: @JanVojtěchVaníček For future reference, when you post in Stack Overflow, you should never say something is simply "not working".   Always tell what error you are getting, or if not an error, what exactly is wrong with the result.  And include the exact code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END` prescription.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    [Value I have],
    CASE WHEN [Value I have] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Value I need]
FROM MyTable;
```